# Query for big query data

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to run query like below

```
SELECT COUNT(event_dim.name) as NumberOfPurchases,
event_dim.params.value.int_value as level
FROM
TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
   com_game_example_ANDROID.app_events_,
   TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-12-31'))
WHERE event_dim.name = 'trigger_purchase'ANDevent_dim.key='ID' AND event_dim.key='KEYWORD'
```

Comment: whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This query is missing `GROUP BY` clause, so in order to run it needs to be

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(event_dim.name) as NumberOfPurchases,
  event_dim.params.value.int_value as level
FROM
TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
   com_game_example_ANDROID.app_events_,
   TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-12-31'))
WHERE event_dim.name = 'trigger_purchase'ANDevent_dim.key='ID' AND event_dim.key='KEYWORD'
GROUP BY level
```

Comment: Please add more detail - what is the error you are getting, what is the job id and project id